# Player.IO Addchild not doing anything

Tags: actionscript-3, player.io

I am trying to add a simple rectangle to my stage.
Code:

```
private function makeBox()
{         
     trace("Test");
     var myBox:Shape = new Shape();
     myBox.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
     myBox.graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 150, 150);
     myBox.graphics.endFill();
     addChild(myBox);         
}
```

But it doesnt do ANYTHING. All I see is a black stage (My stage color is set to black)
It doesnt work with a textfield either...

And yes, my playerio server is running. There are no errors in the console. This function is being run because the trace outputs to the console.

Comment: I don't know player.io, but for ActionScript 3, your code looks fine. Try to verify if there is nothing that can hide your added object ( verify the depth of its parent in reality ) ...

Comment: Can you confirm the box's display list index? `addChild` supposed to put it on top but maybe there are other things happening (i.e. other elements on the list).

Comment: What do you get if you replace `trace("Test");` with `trace(stage);`?

Comment: I got it fixed. Apparently it will only let me addChild from the main class.